# Reconstruction of monoidal categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories, quantum-groups

Both [this post on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15800/calculating-6j-symbols-aka-racah-wigner-coefficients-for-quantum-groups) and [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6-j_symbol) claim that you can reconstruct a monoidal category from its Grothendieck ring and $6j$-symbols (or equivalently the associator).

Bruce Westbury in his post is more careful and asks that this category is semisimple. I can imagine that one can reconstruct a semisimple monoidal category from its Grothendieck ring and associator. But without semisimplicity it seems to me that you are missing a lot of information about the morphisms of this category. (So adding the Auslander algebra would probably suffice to reconstruct it.)

My question is twofold:

1. Can I get some reference proving that you can reconstruct a semisimple monoidal category from its Grothendieck ring and associator?
2. Is it true/false without semisimplicity?